# Affecting two text boxes with single ajax whisperer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fill two text boxes with a single ajax whisperer. I got the following code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="ICZ" id="ICZ">
<input type="text" name="ODB" id="ODB">
```

respond.php:

```
<?php
require_once("../inc/dbconnect.php");
$return_arr = array();

$term=iconv('UTF-8' ,'WINDOWS-1250',$_GET["term"]);
$SQL="some sql";
$RS=sqlsrv_query($Conn,$SQL);

while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($RS)) {
        $id_lekar=iconv('WINDOWS-1250', 'UTF-8',$row["ID_LEKAR"]);
        $jmeno=iconv('WINDOWS-1250', 'UTF-8',$row["JMENO"]); 
        $odborn=iconv('WINDOWS-1250', 'UTF-8',$row["ODBORN"]); 
        $row_array['value'] = $id_lekar;
        $row_array['value1'] = $odborn;
        $row_array['label'] = $id_lekar." - ".$jmeno." - ".$odborn;

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

sqlsrv_close($Conn);
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(function() {$('#ICZ').autocomplete({
        source: 'respond.php',
        minLength:5
    });
});
```

This works but only affect one input field. I would like to fill both so I extend SQL query and extend respond.php with `$row_array['value1']`. Then I try to redone jQuery:

```
$(function() {$('#ICZ').autocomplete({
    minLength: 5,
    source: function(request, response){
    $.ajax({
        url: "respond.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {term: request.term},
        success:function(response){
            var len = response.lenght;
            if (len > 0){
                var icz = response[0]['value'];
                var odb = response[0]['value1'];

                document.getElementById('ICZ').value = icz;
                document.getElementById('ODB').value = odb;
            }
        }

    });

    }
});
});
```

But this just doesn't do much, no errors in console, I can see the GET request going on when I fill the field with 5 and more characters, but no response. When I try access respond.php?term=XXXXX I'm getting same response in both ways.

Comment: take a look at `var len = response.lenght; ` -- should be response.length;

Comment: Thank you i correct that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [JSON.parse](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "respond.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {term: request.term},
    success:function(response){
        var response=JSON.parse(response); // parse json to object
        var len = response.length;
        if (len > 0){
            var icz = response[0].value;
            var odb = response[0].value1; //access values like this

            document.getElementById('ICZ').value = icz;
            document.getElementById('ODB').value = odb;
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look if you need to parse json. Print response in console and check if you need to parse it.

Var result =JSON.parse(response);